# Invoke React App.Render from Blazor Server

Tags: reactjs, blazor-server-side

I have an existing ReactJs application that I want to render within a Blazor page.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work.

In index.tsx I exposed the renderApp function...

(window as any).renderApp = renderApp;

Now to run this function, simply place it in wrapper function that is invoked from within the Blazor app...

window.RenderDomainTool = (count) => {

```
        renderApp();
        
        
    }
```